# How i set correctly addcslashes in my querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine

My query doesn´t take data when i try to introduce in the query the addcslashes

I am working with symfony 4 in local witn xampp php 7.3.3

```
public function findByValue($value)
{
    $value = '%'.addcslashes($value, '%_').'%';
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orWhere('u.name = :val')
        ->orWhere('u.surname = :val')
        ->orWhere('u.email = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

the query works ok whithout the addcslashes but it doesn´t make what i want.

Comment: I think you need to write `LIKE` instead of `=`, if you want to make use of the wildcard `%`.

Comment: but I need to get the data where it appears what I write and not when it's just the same

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. If you want `%` to match zero, one, or multiple characters use `LIKE` if you want `%` to match `%` use `=`.

Comment: Also, you cannot reuse the same parameter name.  Replace :val with :name,:surname,:email.  You can use setParameter to set the values of all three parameters to the same value but they need different names.  And I find it very unlikely that you actually want to use addcslashes.  I think you may be confusing it with older style sql escaping.

Comment: @Cerad I think its legit to use addcslashes, so `WHERE email LIKE "%some_user%"` gets the `_` escaped. In doctrine reusing the same param name works well. (could be a setting, but works for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function findByValue($value)
{
    $value = '%'.addcslashes($value, '%_').'%';
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orWhere('u.name like :val1')
        ->orWhere('u.surname like :val2')
        ->orWhere('u.email like :val3')
        ->setParameter('val1', $value)
        ->setParameter('val2', $value)
        ->setParameter('val3', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```